# Start up ssh connection on startup

Tags: ssh, startup

I need to start a ssh connection to a proxy in order to have access to some resources.

I have written the shell script and managed to run the script successfully.

However, I found it very inconvenient to run it every time I need to use it.

The best I think I should have is run the script in machine startup.

But I have one problem:

After my machine connects with the proxy, the proxy requires me to input the password in order to authenticate.

But how can I tell the shell to "input" the password for me, so I do not need to type it?

Any hint?

**Solution：**

```
set timeout 60
spawn /usr/bin/ssh -D 22 -g name@ssh.sshcenter.info
expect {
"password:" {
send "*******\r"
}
}
interact {
timeout 60 { send " "}
}
```

Then use **expect** command to execute the script.

Very nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a keypair for authentication and don't specify a password for your private key. There are many [tutorials](http://blogs.translucentcode.org/mick/archives/000230.html) for this on the web.

Comment: Unfortunately, the remote server is quite stringy on the command.I do not even have access to command like `cp`. So I think I failed to do that. Actually, the remote server is just proxy for the users to have access to some specific Internet resources. Thanks any way, I learned something new. :-)